# this is undefined in angularjs fullstack MEAN. when using with interval

Tags: angularjs

If i am using this.$onInit(); from other function its working. 
but if make call with function it gives an this is undefined error.

I'm new in angularjs. Please help me to solve this issue.

class ChatComponent {

```
    constructor($http, $scope, socket, Auth, $interval) {
      this.$http = $http;
      this.socket = socket;
      this.users = [];
      this.setView = false;
      this.suggestionResponse = {}; 
      this.$interval = $interval;  
      this.activeConversion = {};   


    this.currentUser = Auth.getCurrentUser()._id;
        console.log(this.currentUser);


     $interval(function() { this.$onInit; },10000);


    }

   $onInit() {
    this.$http.post('/api/conversions/getconversation', {
          userId: this.currentUser
        }).then(response => {
            var conversionArray = response.data[0].conversions; 
            for(var i=0; i < conversionArray.length; i++){

                var metch = this.mergeArray(conversionArray[i]._id, response.data[0].messages); 
            if(metch){ 
                conversionArray[i].message = metch;
            }
            else{
                conversionArray[i].message = [];
            }

            }
            this.users = conversionArray;

        });
    }

  }



}
```

$onInit method simple fetch last messages of conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the top of the controller;

```
var self = this;
```

So self is always refers to the your constructor and in the $onInit() you ca use as

```
self.users = conversionArray
```

Comment: I'm trying above solution but its give same error.

I'm using 

var self = this;
$interval(function() { self.$onInit(); },10000);

Now its working. Anyway thanks for suggestion.